# Most efficient way to pull a specific record from an ActiveRecord collection

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-4

In my database, `Account` has many `Contacts`.

```
class Account < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :contacts
end

class Contact < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :account
end
```

`Contacts` has a field called `primary_contact`, which denotes the record as the primary. In a situation where I need to pull all contacts for an account, and list the primary contact separately, is there an efficient way to pull this primary record out with ActiveRecord, or should I just identify the correct record in the collection that it returns by looking at the values of that field manually?

Ideally I would like to be able to do something like `account.primary_contact` or even `contacts.primary` to identify this, but it's not necessary.

Comment: Is `primary_contact` a boolean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can add a `has_one` association

```
class Account < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :contacts
  has_one :primary_contact, class_name: 'Contact', conditions: { primary_contact: true }
end
```

UPDATE: rails 4 syntax would be

```
has_one :primary_contact, -> { where(primary_contact: true) }, class_name: 'Contact'
```

Comment: Since this answer was first, I tried it and it worked perfectly. Looking at the other answer, though, he's using scope. Is the difference due to the fact that one is tied to Account while the other is tied to Contact?

Comment: the main difference is that having an association declares that you have one primary contact. whereas having a scope just gives you a scope. to get the primary contact for an account (assuming there's only 1 per account), you need to do `account.contacts.primary.first` which you can do with `account.primary_contact`.

Answer (score 1):

```
class Contact < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :account
    scope :primary, where( primary_contact: true )
end
```

Then if you have an account:

```
account.contacts.primary
```

should give you the primary contacts.

Comment: Should `:primary_contact:` have that first :?